# How to bind a windows form control to data with an IValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-addins

I'm trying to change the background color of a form control based on a color in my datasource. I've got the binding to work without any conversion.
How to I use an IValueConverter I've written to do the same?

Example Binding without conversion:

```
this.panel1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(
                "BackColor",
                dataSource,
                "selectedColor",
                false,
                DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<UserControl myControls="clr-namespace:MyProjectRef">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <myControls:MyValueConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{Binding MyCurrentBackgroundProperty, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>

</UserControl>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Sorry, I failed to see this is a Windows Forms issue.

Use the [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events on your binding to effectively create your value converter.

```
Binding backgroundBinding = new Binding("BackColor", dataSource, "selectedColor", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

backgroundBinding.Parse += OnParseBackgroundBinding;
backgroundBinding.Format += OnFormatBackgroundBinding;

this.panel1.DataBindings.Add(backgroundBinding);

private void OnParseBackgroundBinding(object sender, ConvertEventArgs args)
{
    // this is called when the value of the binding changes
    Color background = (Color)args.Value;

    // do your conversion here...
    args.Value = ...
}

private void OnFormatBackgroundBinding(object sender, ConvertEventArgs args)
{
    // this is called when the property of the binding changes

    // do conversion here if necessary...
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to access underlying xml. This is a form for a powerpoint add-in. Designer codebehind is also in c#.

Comment: Can you please add your existing code where you managed to get a binding without conversion then?

Comment: Added a clarification